# Is this theorem correct as a key-lemma to the proof of the integral variable transformation formula?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

As far as I know, "proofs" of variable transformation formulas for integrals of multivariable functions can be divided into two types:

- those that use partitions of unity and
- those that vaguely state that "the volume of the transformed microelements approximates the volume of the map multiplied by the Jacobian" ; in other words, the policy is written, but the proof is not written, nor is the formulation given.

So, I am on a "long journey" to formulate the elementary proof of variable transformations for multivariate function $\varphi$ along to the concept of;
"the volume of the transformed microelements approximates the volume of the map multiplied by the Jacobian,"

As for our "world line," the integral of a multivariable function itself is defined, but the formula for variable transformation is unknown;

Let $\varphi :U \to \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be almost everyware differentiable  in $U$ ,
$U$ be an non-empty Open subset of ${R}^{n}$

**My question**

> Then, I'd like to ask whether the following theorem holds and its proof.

**Theorem**

> Let $ \mathbf{x}\in U$ 
> Then, $\forall \epsilon >0$,
> $\exists \delta>0, \exists I \subset U$ : $n$ dimensional closed interval s,t 
> $$|I|<\delta  \Rightarrow \left|\ \mu[\varphi[I]] - | J{\varphi}_{\mathbf{x}}|\ |I| \ \ \right|< \epsilon $$
>
> Here,
>
> - $\varphi[A] $ represents the mage of A through $\varphi$
> - For $A \in \mathbf{R}^{n}$ 
>    $$\mu[A] := \int_{cl[A]} {\chi}_{cl[A]} \ \ , $$ here, $cl[A]$ is the closure of the $A$　and For $A \subset \mathbb{R}\ ,\ $ $\chi_A$ is the indicator function of $A$, that is; 
>   $\chi_A\colon E \to \{1,0\};\ x \mapsto \chi_A(x) := \begin{cases}
>    1 & \text{ if } x \in A, \\
>    0 & \text{ if } x \notin A
>   \end{cases}$
> - $J{\varphi}_{\mathbf{x}}$ is the Jacobian of $\varphi$ at $\mathbf{x}$
> - An "n-dimensional closed interval" is a set that can be represented by the direct product of closed intervals in $R$.
> - For an n-dimensional closed interval $I=[a_1,b_1]\times [a_2, b_2] \times \cdots \times [a_n, b_n]$, 
>   $$|I|=|b_1 -a_1|*|b_2 -a_2|*\cdots |b_n -a_n|$$

If this theorem could be proved, the following corollary would hold.

**Corollary**

> Under the same assumptions as the above theorem, the following holds;
>
> $$|J{\varphi}_{\mathbf{x}}|\  |I| - \epsilon < \mu[\varphi[I]] < |J{\varphi}_{\mathbf{x}}|\ |I| +\epsilon$$

Using the Corollary above, the following lemma perhaps we can prove the following auxiliary theorem; it must probably be the key to the formula for variable transformation of integrals of multivariate functions.

**Lemma**

> Under the same assumptions as the above theorem, 
> Let $f:V \to \mathbf{R}$ be a Riemann integrable, $\varphi[D]\in V$ and
> $D\subset U$:$n$-dimensional closed interval, then,
>
> $\forall \epsilon >0$,
> $\exists \delta>0\ \ $ ,and $\exists \Delta$ s.t 
> If a  $\Delta$: a partition of the integral-interval $D\ \ $
> satisfies $|\Delta|<\delta$, then
> $$\sum_{I\in \Delta} f(min_{[f]} [I])(|J\varphi_{min_{[f]} [I])}|\ |I| - \epsilon)
> <\int_{\varphi[D]}  f(\mathbf{x}) 
> <\sum_{I\in \Delta} f(max_{[f]} [I])(|J\varphi_{max_{[f]} [I])}|\ |I| + \epsilon)$$
>
> Here,
>
> - $max_{[f]} [I]\in I$ is an element of $I$, s,t,
>   $$\forall\mathbf{x} \in I,\ \   f(\mathbf{x})\leq f(max_{[f]} [I])$$
> - $min_{[f]} [I]\in I$ is an element of $I$, s,t,
>   $$\forall\mathbf{x} \in I,\ \   f(\mathbf{x})\geq f(min_{[f]} [I])$$
> - For the partition of the integral interval $D$, $\Delta$, $|\Delta|$ is a number s,t, $$\forall I\in \Delta,\ \ \ |I|<|\Delta| .$$